# Name of serialization format

Tags: serialization, byte

I have written a dead-simple serialization format which encodes unsigned integers by first converting them into bytes in big-endian form and then prefixing them with a single byte specifying the number of bytes which the number takes up. Eg. `3 = 01 03`, `268 = 02 01 0C`.  The range of integers is therefore `0` to `2^255 - 1`.

I use this to serialize strings by prefixing the string with the encoding of its length, and I can then serialize arbitrary structures quite easily, for example a list of strings is an encoding of the number of elements followed by the encoding of each of the strings.

Here it is in PHP: https://gist.github.com/4577886.

My question is: What do you call this method of serialization? Is it very often used? Is there anything wrong with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of type-length-value, without the type. And that's what's wrong with it. How do you know whether the next 4 bytes are an int or a string or a 4-byte array?

Comment: The serialization is statically typed. Your code should know what the expected type is of the bytes it is reading, and any failure which then occurs in parsing is considered corrupt data.

Comment: Also I'm accepting this answer because "type-length-value" is indeed the name I was looking for.